# Can't screen share in Zoom session on Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, zoom-meeting

I'm using Zoom (Version 5.5.2), and when I start screen sharing from a Zoom session, I get the following popup:

[image]

> Can not start share, we only support Wayland on GNOME with Ubuntu 17 and above, Fedora 25 and above, Debian 9 and above, CentOS 8 and above, OpenSUSE Leap 15 and above, Oracle Linux 8 and above, Arch Linux, AnterGos, **Manjaro**. If your OS is not on the list, please use x11 instead.

But I'm running Manjaro, which is in the list of mentioned OS'es. I found this [blogpost](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2020/06/22/fixing-zoom-screen-sharing-on-debian-unstable/) where a similar problem was addressed on Debian Unstable, by adding the missing version information to "usr/lib/os-release".

My "/usr/lib/os-release" file doesn't contain any Version information either:

```
NAME="Manjaro Linux"
ID=manjaro
ID_LIKE=arch
BUILD_ID=rolling
PRETTY_NAME="Manjaro Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="32;1;24;144;200"
HOME_URL="https://manjaro.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://wiki.manjaro.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://manjaro.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.manjaro.org/"
LOGO=manjarolinux
```

As far as I can tell, this information is in "/etc/lsb-release" which contains:

```
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.2.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Nibia
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux
```

Should I just add these contents to "/usr/lib/os-release" as that blog suggests? Will this fix my problem, or should I do something else?

Will this break anything? The general advice seems to be that I shouldn't manually be editing "usr/lib/os-release" anyway.

Comment: To start: Zoom only supports Wayland in conjunction with Gnome. Is that your case?

Comment: @harrymc I have the Gnome version of Manjaro installed, if that's what you mean. Version 3.38.2 to be precise.

Comment: Are you using Wayland?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, that's the Windowing system, according to the system settings.

Comment: Have you tried opening a ticket with Zoom support?

Comment: @HackSlash No, I haven't. I have a free account, so all I see on the Zoom support page is the "virtual chat bot", and the help-pages, none of which helped me.

Comment: @cigien this looks like a problem that only Zoom support can solve. If you want them to support Linux you might have to pay for support. You can also try Wine or a Windows VM.

Comment: @HackSlash Hmm, Zoom *does* support Linux though, including Manjaro. I've been using it without issues for quite a while. The linked blog in my question in fact fixed a very similar problem on a different Linux flavor, so it feels like something that could be fixed on my end.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**
Your problem will very likely be solved by updating the package.

> I'm using Zoom (Version 5.5.2) [...]

You don't mention how you've installed the software. It's either one of two options, via download of the package labelled "Arch" from the zoom website or from the [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository). The latter is less error prone and more end-user friendly.

#### Limitation to Wayland/gnome

> **A commenter wrote**
> To start: Zoom only supports Wayland in conjunction with Gnome. Is that your case?

This *might* be the vendor's legal department's official stance (I neither veri- not falsified), but given the nature of this platform, I am assuming "supports" in the above to primarily have technical, not so much a legal connotation.

*Technically* speaking, the above is minimum misleading, if not outright a false claim.

#### Sidenote: [`extra/plasma-wayland-session`](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/plasma-wayland-session/)

Since KDE 5.3 [`KWin`](https://community.kde.org/KWin/Wayland) *can* spawn a nested session under Wayland *and* X11.
Since 5.4 it's capable of managing Wayland clients and can start a `plasma` session under Wayland.

Hence, even if all other notions from above were true, a mitigation strategy would exist.
But it's not even needed.

#### `zoom-5.6`

Until 20min ago, I had never attempted to run `zoom` on my personal machine.
Given your experience, I expected to encounter *some* obstacle on the way, however, from installation to a working screenshare on an up to date system (i.e. kernel `linux-5.10.23-1-MANJARO` with `zoom-5.6.0-1`) took less than 60 seconds.

#### Installing from the AUR

Either way, remove the previously installed version, *if* it was downloaded off the web.

Should you be familiar, use your [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers) of choice and install [`zoom`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/zoom/).

Should you be reading this acronym for the first time:

- Give it 10min and [read up](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) on the AUR
- Install an [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers).
  I'd recommend [`rua`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rua/), others work as well.
- Install `zoom`.
- Share your screen:

```bsh
# install dependencies for building `rua`
sudo pacman -Syu --needed git base-devel bubblewrap-suid xz shellcheck cargo
```

```bsh
# install `rua` (manually) from AUR sources
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/rua.git && cd rua && makepkg -si
```

Now this will properly handle dependency resolution for you:

```bsh
# use `rua` to install `zoom` from the AUR (no `sudo` needed)
rua install zoom
```

#### Maintaining your installed packages: Updating / Removing

```bsh
# upgrade AUR packages
# rua will prompt you whether is should thereafter call `pacman` to install
rua upgrade
```

```bsh
# remove a currently installed package
sudo pacman -R <package-name>
```

`rua` never really *installs* anything, it facilitates downloading from the AUR and building packages that `pacman` can consume (as per `PKGBUILD` file). Hence, removal is like any ol' package from the official repos, `pacman -R`.

#### Addendum

> Should I just add these contents to "/usr/lib/os-release" as that blog suggests?

No.
The error message displayed on screen aside, the two problems have little to no overlap exactly.

Comment: Thanks, installing zoom via rua worked perfectly, I have 5.6 now, and screen sharing works. I had previously installed zoom-client via snapd, and I got an old version of the zoom software I assume.

Comment: If I don't find an application I'd like / need to use in the official repos, my next move always is the google search query `<application-name> arch aur`. Chances are decent you'll find what you were looking for. In conjunction with `<application-name> arch wiki` you can get pretty far without additional resources. The arch wiki is amazing. Simply exemplary. If an Oscar or Emmy for wikis existed, this would have won several. Also, consistently search for `arch`, rather than `manjaro`. Manjaro is a great distribution, don't get me wrong, just not a helpful search term.